# Regex in bash 4.1.2

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to list files using regex but it's not getting listed as expected.

```
# ls test*.tgz
test-2012_07_17_11_23_45.tgz
```

But when I use little drilled regex it's failing.

```
# ls test-[0-9]{4}_*.tgz
ls: cannot access test-[0-9]{4}_*.tgz: No such file or directory

# ls test-[0-9]\{4\}_*.tgz
ls: cannot access test-[0-9]{4}_*.tgz: No such file or directory

# ls "test-"[0-9]\{4\}"_"*".tgz"
ls: cannot access test-[0-9]{4}_*.tgz: No such file or directory
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash does not support glob expansion via regular expressions.  You need to use glob syntax or extglob syntax, neither of which allows {4} for number of occurrences.

Try `ls | pcregrep' or something like that instead, or provide more info on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

#### Globs Aren't Regular Expressions

Bash does not do regular expression file matches. Shells generally do [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) with "globs." You can turn on extended globs with `shopt -s extglob`, but you still need to perform globbing on its own terms. For example, this will match your file:

```
shopt -s extglob

# Would match: test-2011_07_17_11_23_45.tgz test-2012_07_17_11_23_45.tgz
ls test-+(+([[:digit:]])_*tgz)

# Would match: test-2011_07_17_11_23_45.tgz
ls test-!(2012*)
```

In this example, the extended globs are not really necessary. You could do the same thing more easily with standard globs. However, they provide some simple examples of what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Bash expands glob patterns, not regular expressions.